Is there a way to make product creation required/mandatory when user is creating opportunity?
When user is creating a new opportunity can we make it mandatory to add a new product. I know about "Opportunity Settings" on setup that we can use to prompt "add products to Opportunities" modal/pop-up but is there any way to make it mandatory or any other way to make product creation mandatory when user is creating opportunity.

You can't create a child record before you create a parent record. In other words, you can't require a user to add products to an opportunity that doesn't exist yet. What you can do is prevent any other edits before moving on through a validation rule:
AND(NOT(IsNew()), NOT(ISCHANGED(Pricebook2Id), NOT( HasOpportunityLineItem ))

This rule allows the user to create the Opportunity, select a Price Book, and then add items.

Thanks @sfdcfox, but I have a flow which runs after opportunity is created and whenever I am using a validation like above it's resulting in error

@Ajit In that case, you'll need to either change the flow or validation rule to account for this configuration.

Thanks @sfdcfox, Is there any way to change validation rule to account for this configuration?
